# Load a child view based on a condition in ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the code below, by default all the three views will be loaded. But I would like to load the options view by default and either workspaceDetailed or workspaceList view should be loaded based on a condition. How exactly to achieve that?

### template

```html
<span ui-sref="workarea.user">Load</span>
  <ui-view="options" />
  <ui-view="workspaceList" />
  <ui-view="workspaceDetailed" />
```

### router

```js
.state("workarea.user", {
  url: "^/workarea/?path",
  requireLogin: true,
  views: {
    "options": {
      templateUrl: "/views/options.html",
      controller: "optionsCtrl"
    },
    "workspaceList": {
      templateUrl: "/views/workspaceList.html",
      controller: "workspaceListCtrl"
    },
    "workspaceDetailed": {
      templateUrl: "/views/workspaceDetailed.html",
      controller: "workspaceDetailedCtrl"
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Where does the logic to control which view to show reside?

Comment: The question is, where and how exactly to embed the control? You can assume if x = 1 , show workspaceDetailed , else workspaceList.

Comment: I understand the question. I'm asking, at what level `x=1` is decided. If it's decided at the scope that encompasses the HTML that you have above, then the question is trivial